# How to set the request for a test inside a helper spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**tl;dr: How to test a helper that depends on the current request URI?**

I'm trying to implement in my Helper spec a test to the `nav_link` method, which provides a link with the `active` class if on the current page:

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def nav_link(link_text, link_path, options = {})
    active = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
    link_to link_text, link_path, class: 'nav-item nav-link ' << active, **options
  end
end
```

In order to do so, I need to set the correct request for each test, so I can test whether the method is providing the link with the `active` class:

```rb
# spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb
describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "#nav_link" do    
    it 'sets the active link class' do

      # "set here the request to users_path"

      expect(helper.nav_link('Users', users_path)).to include('active')
    end
end
```

So far I've experimented with the `feature` and `request` spec types, but couldn't find a way to implement this on the `helper` spec, so I could test the isolated function call and it's return.

---

A solution to the active link feature was achieved using the `active_link_to` gem, but still the question about the test continues.

Comment: short answer: do a feature spec.

Comment: Yes I have thought about doing a feature spec. But what I need to have tested is not a feature, just the isolated helper.

Comment: As an alternative, don't test it. It's literally one condition (and the rest is rails code). I think you can be quite sure that it works. :)

Comment: controller and helper specs are notorious for being annoying to set up.

Comment: here's another idea: __pass__ current path in a parameter. Yes, your helper invocations will be slightly uglier, but in return you now don't depend on request!